# conflicting types for '-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(int)row'

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I have this code:

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(int)row
{
    if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"friend name"]) {
        if (row == 0) {
            return @"All friends";
        } else {
            return [[friendsArray objectAtIndex:row - 1] name];
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

And I get this warning, although the program runs as expected:

```
conflicting types for '-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(int)row'
```

How can I get rid of this warning? Thanks.

---

Answers related to `UITableViews` instead of `NSTableViews` will be **down voted**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 10.5, the definition of this was changed to:

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row;
```

Note the use of `NSInteger` versus `int`.